# setfacl inherit permissions without bash scripting

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, file-permissions, setfacl

i have this script to add inherit permissions in all directory's,

```
asd=$(find -type d); for a in $asd; do setfacl -d -m "u:pythoncrons:rwx" $a; done
```

my question is, i can set inherit permissions recursive without bash script?

like recursive set permissions command:

```
setfacl -R -m "u:pythoncrons:rwx" directory
```

If someone knows any software that handles VCL that may be useful for this, it would also be fine.

UPDATE #1

i actually using this because is more easy:

```
find -type d -exec setfacl -d -m "u:pythoncrons:rwx" {} \;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), for example:

```
find <where> -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 setfacl -R -m "u:pythoncrons:rwx"
```

> xargs reads items from the standard input, [...] and executes the command [...] one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input.

Comment: my question is, Can I do this without resorting to another command? only with setfacl or other VCL framework?, i don't understand why i can apply changes recursive with files but not with directory's, Has anyone thought about this?